# Stripe: Get refund created by charges.refund

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

When a refund is issued by the stripe api, it returns the charge object, but doesn't specify which refund was created. Moreover, there appears to be some ambiguity in the documentation, as the text says

> Returns the refund object if the refund succeeded. Throws (...)

, which is exactly what the curl example shows. However, the node (and other languages) example response clearly shows that the entire charge object is returned, which would make it difficult to determine which refund was created.

Perhaps [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#refund_charge) of the example response is incorrect, in which case my problem is already solved.

How should I determine which refund id is the one that was created? Sort by created time and use the newest one? (What's the sort order of the refunds?) Use some undocumented part of the response?

Comment: I've run into the same issue with the documentation and was hoping someone had found a definitive answer re: whether the return object is the charge (as illustrated) or the refund (as stated). Did you ever find out?

Comment: @Semicolon the EXAMPLE RESPONSE in the documentation seems to currently be incorrect; only the created refund is returned from the createRefund method. The stripe.charges.refund method still returns the full charge, however.

One neat thing with their documentation though, is that you can use the key and charge ids to actually run the queries and see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I figured this was the more likely case, since it seems consistent with how other calls work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a momentary discrepancy in the stripe api docs where the api was being updated, but the node client library had not yet been updated. The old api was

```
stripe.charges.refund
```

, which returns the charge, and the new api is

```
stripe.charges.createRefund
```

, which returns the refund.

Comment: i'm confused by the documentation. do i need to pass in the 'charge id', or the entire charge object? to charget.createRefund ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can catch EVENT from stripe webhook

"charge.refunded"
https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-charge.refunded

Comment: Yeah, events are definitely something that they added since I last used stripe.